# Not redirecting to AuthPage when sign out

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get createa signout function for my app, but the problem is while that it sign the user out, I have to hot restart the app to make it back to the loginpage. And when I tried to Navigtor.push that out, I could not log back in but still have to restart the app.
AuthEvent

```
part of 'auth_bloc.dart';

@immutable
sealed class AuthEvent {}

final class AuthSignUp extends AuthEvent {
  final String email;
  final String password;
  final String username;

  AuthSignUp(
      {required this.email, required this.password, required this.username});
}

final class AuthLogin extends AuthEvent {
  final String email;
  final String password;

  AuthLogin({required this.email, required this.password});
}

final class AuthIsUserLoggedIn extends AuthEvent {}

final class AuthSignOut extends AuthEvent {
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

final class AuthResetPassword extends AuthEvent {
  final String password;
  final String newPassword;

  AuthResetPassword({required this.password, required this.newPassword});
}
```

AuthState

```
part of 'auth_bloc.dart';

@immutable
sealed class AuthState {
  const AuthState();
}

final class AuthInitial extends AuthState {}

final class AuthLoading extends AuthState {}

final class AuthSuccess extends AuthState {
  final User user;
  const AuthSuccess(this.user);
}

final class AuthFailure extends AuthState {
  final String message;
  const AuthFailure(this.message);
}

final class LogOutSuccessState extends AuthState {
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}
```

part of AuthBloc

```
void _onSignOut(AuthSignOut event, Emitter<AuthState> emit) async {
    final res = await _signOut(signOut_usecase.NoParams());
    res.fold(
      (failure) => emit(AuthFailure(failure.message)),
      (_) => emit(LogOutSuccessState()),
    );
  }
```

how I implement that into a page

```
GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print("fdsfdsfdsfdsfsdf");
                      context.read<AuthBloc>().add(AuthSignOut());
                    },
                    //_displayProfileSheet(context);
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                    )),
```

AuthPage

```
class AuthPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<AuthPage> createState() => _AuthPageState();
}

class _AuthPageState extends State<AuthPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<AuthBloc>().add(AuthIsUserLoggedIn());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocSelector<AppUserCubit, AppUserState, bool>(
        selector: (state) {
          return state is AppUserLoggedIn;
        },
        builder: (context, isLoggedIn) {
          print("log in");

          if (isLoggedIn) {
            return ScreenWrapper();
          }

          return const LogInOrRegisterPage();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a listener for the login state in MaterialApp. When it detects that the state is logged out, it will navigate to the login page.

```
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  NavigatorState get _navigator => _navigatorKey.currentState!;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return BlocListener<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if(state is AuthSuccess){
              _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => const HomePage()),(route) => false,
              );
            }
            if(state is LogOutSuccessState ){
              _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => const LogInOrRegisterPage()),(route) => false,
              );
            }
          },
          child: child,
        );
      },
      onGenerateRoute: (_) => SplashPage.route(),
    );
  }
}
```